# howto get subsection padding in gnu-assembler

Tags: variables, assembly, linker, gnu-assembler, msp430

I'm using gnu assembler on a TI MCU (msp430) and want to define variables of mixed alignments in assembly; some are byte aligned, others must be word (16bit) aligned.  I am also needing to keep some variables private to an assembly language module, and others common (global).  So, I'd like to us .lcomm -- as the default, and then use .global to over-ride it when appropriate.

But even after applying the byte align directive, I am getting alignment errors during linking of a GCC compiled program:

ssegLED.c:200: dangerous relocation: unaligned address

And that line is merely trying to access data that is supposed to be word aligned:

if (knob) { ... }

In the assembly language module causing the problem, I'm trying to make the data pack efficiently into memory;  So I want to use subsections to group like kinds of data together so that holes don't form between differently aligned data.  eg: all word aligned data I'd like in the default subsection (0) but unaligned data, I want in subsection 1.

Here's the assembly / .s code used to define four variables:  keystroke, quadrature, keystate, and knob.  The first three are byte aligned, the last is word aligned.

```
.section    .bss    ;; doesn't matter if .bss or .section .bss -- same err.
.subsection 1
.balign     1 ;; can add a  ,0 -- but it changes nothing

.global     keystroke
.type       keystroke,@object
.size       keystroke,1 ;; Tried with and without this line, no change...
.lcomm      keystroke,1

.lcomm      quadrature,1
.lcomm      keystate,1  

.section    .bss
.subsection 0
.balign     2 ;; tried adding ,0 -- but it fixes nothing

.global     knob  ;; Present knob value
.type       knob, @object
.size       knob, 2     ;; doesn't affect error whether commented out/not
.lcomm      knob, 2
```

Now, there are two things I am doing which ought to prevent mis-alignement issues;
According to the GNU AS manual, subsection 0 should be placed in memory before subsection 1; therefore section 0 automatically starts out word aligned as the default section; and secondly, I'm using the .balign directive explicitly.

But it doesn't work... and changing to .b2align doesn't fix it, etc.

I *can* make the error go away by explicitly adding another byte aligned variable to the the subsection 1 variables keystroke, quadrature, and keystate; so that the whole subsection ends on a word boundary; but as the offending subsection has a lower number (0), the alignment of subsection (1) ought not have any effect....

Secondly, if I change all the .lcomm into .comm the error also goes away; but I have no idea why.

What's going on? and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`.lcomm` puts your symbol into the `.bss` section (subsection 0) implicitly, no matter what the current section or subsection is. As such your symbols are simply in the order they appear in the source, that is why `knob` comes after the single-byte variables. It's also why `.balign` makes no difference, since that applies to the current (sub)section.

Try using `.fill` instead. According to my tests that seems to work.

Comment: Yes indeed.... undocumented behavior.  It's weird that fill would even work on a section which rejects data.  But, it does seem to work -- so overall, this looks like a bug in "as" design or documentation.  I'm not sure how to report it -- but I think I'll just make a macro for now to use .fill, which can be easily changed if the problem is ever fixed.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Everything is documented that I said. You can use the `.skip` directive if you think that's more readable. I don't see any problem in GAS apart from having multiple directives doing the same thing. Maybe I didn't explain the situation clearly enough.